# Running multiple remote commands via a single ssh command

Tags: shell, ssh

```
sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no a.user@IP "Command1 ; Command2"
```

When i try to run multiple commands after ssh it only runs the 1st command and exits after that without executing others.

I am running the above command,
Could I improve on it to run all the commands sequentially?

Comment: We need a [mre]. `"Command1; Command2"` runs both Command1 and Command2. There _are_ possible commands that would have the bug you describe, but you have to show us one for us to say why it happens in that specific situation and how to avoid it.

Comment: BTW, I took out "at once" because it implies in parallel, but you explicitly say you want things to run sequentially.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I meant running the commands sequentially by giving a single line of commands "at once".

Comment: I realized that was what you meant after clicking through and reading the question body, but it wasn't what I thought you meant looking at the title in the list of questions on the front page. Since the purpose of a title is to give people an accurate summary of what the body will contain...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy                                                              Command is sshpass -p Password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no a.user@IP "show memory statistics ; Show crypto mib ipsec flowmib global"                          Result:

Unauthorized Access Prohibited
Result of 1st command
"Load for five secs: 36%/1%; one minute: 35%; five minutes: 35%
Time source is NTP, 05:01:14.368 JST Sat May 14 2022

Tracekey : 1#6671756b0fd6e3ea213e1e6ccee7284e

                Head    Total(b)     Us........."packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe

Comment: Ahh -- so the remote shell isn't sh or bash

Comment: ...unfortunately, this is beyond the control of your local copy of ssh: it sends a string, the remote system decides how to split it up and interpret it.

Comment: I assume this is a network device of some sort? Do you know which ssh implementation it uses? If it's one that allows multiple channels per transport, you can just run each command in a different channel but keep the transport open. Unfortunately, some very-low-memory embedded ssh servers don't support that either.

Comment: Note that the "shell" tag is generally aimed at questions about POSIX-y shells, and it looks very likely that the system you're ssh'ing into doesn't have one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is definitely not bash.

Comment: One thing you could try is having a literal newline in your string. `ssh remotehost $'command1\ncommand2'` -- note that this requires your _local_ shell to be bash. Still, it's a tossup whether that will work; I wouldn't bet any money on it. Another thing you can try is providing the commands in a heredoc: `ssh remotehost <<'EOF'`, then `command1` on one line, `command2` on another, then an `EOF`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, it is network device. But when i copy paste all the commands after having logged in, it runs them all sequentially.

Comment: But without knowing the device you're ssh'ing into and the details of its shell, this is all just guesswork.

Comment: Yes, but passing a command on the ssh command line and passing it on a remote tty are completely different codepaths. They don't work anything like the same way; writing a SSH server to handle the two approaches, one is writing two entirely different handlers.

Comment: If you want to emulate the remote TTY approach in a way that's true to how a user at a keyboard looks to the remote server, then you want to use a tool like `expect` (a very old TCL-based tool), `pexpect` (a slightly newer Pythonic alternative) or similar. The heredoc approach I referenced earlier is _kinda_ close, but the timing isn't the same so it may or may not work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have tried adding a new line in my string literally,  it failed without output of even a single command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Anyway, Thanks for the insight. This was my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Doesn't any posix-y shell allows **literal** newlines inside quoted strings (not `\n`, actual <kbd>RETURN</kbd>)?

Comment: @jhnc I believe so, yes. Can't demonstrate that in a comment, though.

Comment: BTW, the reason I was saying the heredoc approach may or may not work is that I've seen embedded ssh daemons that shut everything down the moment they see their first EOF on any file descriptor, without flushing buffers first. It should be reported as a bug to the vendor if that behavior is ever encountered, but, well, bugs do exist.